# accessing database

Tags: c#, .net, sql

Here is my problem; I have a hosted and published database on godaddy servers. I have also published my website. However, when I tried to use one of visual studio's tools such as chart, or data view or any tool that wants me to specify a data source, I get the

```
"error 40: could not open a connection to sql server".
```

In most cases, I have worked around this issue by writing the code instead of using these tools on the ".cs" sections, but now I need to update my database model and I really would prefer not to write that amount of code. The connection string I choose works perfectly, it can update and gather values from database on the published website. But when I Right click on the models section and select "update model from database" the update wizard cannot access the database with the very same connection string. Like I said, this problem occurs on every tool that wants me to select a data source.

Is this a permission issue regarding visual studio or something else? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but... Is your connection string pointing to a local server in the Godaddy network? Say they gave you that the server is "ms.sql" or something like that. Are you pointing to an actual IP address or some URL?

Comment: No it actually points to a URL ends with ".com", sorry I cannot give the entire address here.

Comment: Yeah, no worries. Have you tried to use the IP instead of domain?

Comment: I have, I get the same error unfortunately.

Comment: And what about server port? Have you checked that? You can be sure that this isn't a VS problem but a connectivity problem. Oh, I forgot other thing: have you tried to disable Windows Firewall (or any other)???

Comment: Yes, I have granted permission to necessary ports, I think if there was a connection problem then I would never be able to display datas on the website. Like I said, the connection string has no problems if I use it through the code, it only produces this error when I use visual studio tools to select the connection string.

Comment: weird right? :) thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Go Daddy does not allow access to your database from anything other than your shared hosting account.  We allow you direct database access from other locations if you select that option at the time you created the database.  If you did not select this option when you created the database you will never be able to connect to it from a location other than your hosting account.  If you did not select this option at the time you created the database and need to add that option you will have to create a new database with the option selected.

Comment: is there a way to check if the created database allows direct access?

Comment: Yes you can.  Log into your Go Daddy account >> Click My Account at the top left >> Click the + next to Web Hosting >> Click Launch for the hosting account >> Click the correct database type from the Databases drop down >> Click Details from the Actions drop down for the database in question.

Comment: Hm. it does not say anything about whether it is allowed or not, guess that means it is not allowed?